# Can't coerce R to use "." as decimal point

Tags: r, dataset, decimal

I can't coerce **R** to use "." as decimal point, although I used the argument: 'dec=","'

```
read.table("http://www.loaditup.de/files/783502_n4vrencc5p.txt",dec=",")
```

The [data](http://www.loaditup.de/files/783502_n4vrencc5p.txt) is available online.

Note: the NA's in my data set are marked as ".", this may be the origin of this problem...

Has anyone any suggestion how I could make **R** to read in the data with "." as decimal point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your numbers are quoted, so they are read in as text.

```
DF <- read.table("http://www.loaditup.de/files/783502_n4vrencc5p.txt", na.strings=".")
DF$DTCHGUS <- as.numeric(gsub(",",".",DF$DTCHGUS))

head(DF)
#        Date DTCHGUS
#1         NA  1.9020
#2 1980-01-01      NA
#3 1980-01-02  1.8922
#4 1980-01-03  1.8900
#5 1980-01-04  1.8910
#6 1980-01-07  1.8890
```

Comment: Thank you 100 times! I also came across "Pattern Matching and Replacement" and "gsub", but as I never used it, couldn't see which one of them to use and how. Can you recomment a good (online available) document where they explain when to use which of the suggested functions?

Comment: I have nothing better than `?gsub`.